# Until yesterday he had never experienced such anxiety and worry

Tags: past-perfect

Yesterday he became very anxious and worried. It was the most excruciating anxiety and worry he has ever experienced.

> Until yesterday he had never experienced such anxiety and worry.

> Until yesterday he had never become so anxious and worried.

> Until yesterday he had never become anxious and worried to such an extent.

I think the first and second sentences are correct. The third is wrong. I think "become" should be changed to "been".

Would anyone tell me if I'm correct?

Answer (score 1):

They're all acceptable.

I would prefer "been" in both the second *and* third sentences, but *become* is not necessarily wrong. It implies that he became anxious in response to something.

If it wasn't in response to something, i.e. you don't know the cause of the anxiety, use "been".

P.S. In the first one, "such" sounds a little affected, a little older or higher register. Normally I'd say "so much".